# Recursion in C , need some explanation

Tags: c, recursion

I've got this code piece :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int m, int n)
{
  printf("A: m = %i, n = %i\n", m, n);
  while (m < n)
  {
  foo(m + 1, n - 1);
  n -= 5;
  }
  printf("E: m = %i, n = %i\n", m, n);
}

int main(void)
{
  foo(6, 14);
  return 0;
}
```

> I expected code to stop running after `m=10` and `n=10` but it doesn't stop. I don't understand why I get the output:

```
A: m = 6, n = 14
A: m = 7, n = 13
A: m = 8, n = 12
A: m = 9, n = 11
A: m = 10, n = 10
E: m = 10, n = 10 // I expected program to stop here
E: m = 9, n = 6
E: m = 8, n = 7
A: m = 8, n = 7
E: m = 8, n = 7
E: m = 7, n = 3
A: m = 7, n = 8
A: m = 8, n = 7
E: m = 8, n = 7
E: m = 7, n = 3
E: m = 6, n = 4
```

Can someone explain why this is the output?

Comment: ...because it is suppossed to..? What you want to know exactly?

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: but why does it print something like E: m = 9, n = 6 out . and what does -=5 in code mean.

Comment: @IgorRatuschny i see the problem... Mention the output you expected and the output you are getting in the question

Comment: 1. Run this in a debugger. 2. Put a breakpoint on the `E:` printf statement. 3. Run the program and wait for the breakpoint. 4. Look at the call-stack and ask yourself how each of those recursions eventually *exits* the function call it activates. I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest you need an `if`, not `while`, in this code, and a well-placed `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Running your program in a debugger should clarify your doubts. Or even adding some additional `printf` can help to see what is happening. But still let me try for the sake of it.

```
foo(6, 14) expands to:
======================
Prints "A: m = 6, n = 14"
Calls foo(7, 13);  -- (i)
Calls foo(7, 8);   -- (ii)
Prints "A: m = 6, n = 4"

So to know the final output, we need to see what 
    foo(7, 13) -- (i), and 
    foo(7, 8)  -- (ii)
expand to.
```

Lets see step by step. Lets deal with (i), i.e. foo(7, 13 first)

```
Call to foo(7,13)  <--> expanding (i) 
=====================================
Prints "A: m = 7, n = 13"
Calls foo(8, 12)   -- (iii)
Calls foo(8, 7)    -- (iv)
Prints "A: m = 7, n = 3"

Call to foo(8,12)  <--> expanding (iii)
=======================================
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 12"
Calls foo(9, 11)   -- (v) 
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"

Call to foo(9,11)  <--> expanding (v) 
=======================================
Prints "A: m = 9, n = 11"
Calls foo(10,10)  -- (vi)
Prints "A: m = 9, n = 6"

Call to foo(10,10)  <--> expanding (vi)
=======================================
Prints "A: m = 10, n = 10"
Prints "A: m = 10, n = 10"

Now, substituting (vi) in (v), foo(9, 11) expands to
===================================================
Prints "A: m = 9, n = 11"
Prints "A: m = 10, n = 10"
Prints "A: m = 10, n = 10"
Prints "A: m = 9, n = 6"

Now, substituting (v) in (iii), foo(8, 12) expands to
=====================================================
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 12"
Prints "A: m = 9, n = 11"
Prints "A: m = 10, n = 10"
Prints "A: m = 10, n = 10"
Prints "A: m = 9, n = 6"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"

Coming back to (iv), call to foo(8, 7) <--> expanding (iv)
==========================================================
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"

Now, subsituting (iii) and (iv) in (i), i.e. foo(7, 13) expands to - call it "part A"
==============================================================================
Prints "A: m = 7, n = 13"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 12"
Prints "A: m = 9, n = 11"
Prints "A: m = 10, n = 10"
Prints "A: m = 10, n = 10"
Prints "A: m = 9, n = 6"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"
Prints "A: m = 7, n = 3"
```

Okay, part (i), i.e. foo(7, 13)  is done. Lets deal with part(ii), i.e.  foo(7, 8)
    now:

```
Call to foo(7, 8) <--> expanding (ii)
=====================================
Prints "A: m = 7, n = 8"
Calls foo(8, 7)    -- (vii)
Prints "A: m = 7, n = 3"

Call to foo(8, 7)  <--> expanding (vii)
=======================================
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"

Substituting (vii) in (ii), foo(7,8), i.e. (ii) expands to - call it "part B"
============================================================================
Prints "A: m = 7, n = 8"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"
Prints "A: m = 8, n = 7"
Prints "A: m = 7, n = 3"
```

Okay, part (ii), i.e. foo(7, 8) is also done. So, now that we know
what (i) and (ii) expand to, we can know the final output:

```
Call of foo(6, 14), expands to
==============================
"A: m = 6, n = 14"
Part "A"
Part "B"
"A: m = 6, n = 4"

i.e. as follows:

"A: m = 6, n = 14"
"A: m = 7, n = 13"
"A: m = 8, n = 12"
"A: m = 9, n = 11"
"A: m = 10, n = 10"
"A: m = 10, n = 10"
"A: m = 9, n = 6"
"A: m = 8, n = 7"
"A: m = 8, n = 7"
"A: m = 8, n = 7"
"A: m = 7, n = 3"
"A: m = 7, n = 8"
"A: m = 8, n = 7"
"A: m = 8, n = 7"
"A: m = 7, n = 3"
"A: m = 6, n = 4"
```

If this explaination is not confusing, then you should be able to see why the output you are getting is as expected.

I guess, you are missing remaining print statements for below reason:

-- You are ignoring the print statement after the while loop, which is executed when the `foo` returns from one level below.